# Converting polar equations to cartesian

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Convert the equation $r\sin(\theta)=-6\sin(2\theta)$ to cartesian coordinates.

I get that $y=r\sin\theta$ so $y=-6\sin(2\theta)$. From there I don't know where to go, so can someone please explain to me how this is converted to $(x+6)^2+y^2=6^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{equation}
r\sin(\theta) = -12\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\\
r = -12 \cos(\theta)\\
r^2 = -12x\\
x^2 + 12x + y^2 = 0\\
(x+6)^2 - 6^2 + y^2 = 0
\end{equation}

Comment: ah dah...i didn't think to expand the $sin2\theta$, thanks @Atbey